# Form array loop with validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have list of delivery address using form array but initially I have to show every delivery address when user click on particular delivery address show pop up then fill every field if filed is not valid I have to show error symbol on particular delivery address. Here I don't know how to push every delivery address to the pop up. You can see here full working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4jruv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I have tried to send every form with click event like this but I don't know how to handle and display as form

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

        <div formArrayName="addresses" >
            <div *ngFor="let address of myForm.controls.addresses.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">

                <div [formGroupName]="i" class="myform">
         <span (click)="test(address)"> Delivery address {{i+1}}</span>
                </div><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

But I want to do something like this:

[image]

If you see in this picture I have all list of delivery addresses that user can selects from dropdown whenever user click on particular address it must show form then validate if it is valid I have to remove error symbol otherwise I have to keep symbol.

This is something difficult to achieve this. Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Try by adding a property "isValid" to  myForm.controls.addresses.controls model then you have a property to change for every adress element. obviously you must to do the validation  to show or hide  the validation text or error icon.

Comment: That's good idea i will try that

Comment: Hello @AbelValdez valdey i do not get into that how to validate can you please explain some more here is modified working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5nwa9?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hello @U rock, is now fixed. [example modified](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrcrxs)

Comment: Thank you @AbelValdez this is what i want. Bit what if i have 10 to 20 required controls then  i have to declare every control in condition (*ngIf). If you post as answer i will accept.

Comment: You can call a function `validatingForm(addreess)` send adress as parameter and do the validation in **component.ts**.

Comment: Hi @AbelValdez i did call a function in `*ngIf="invalidform(address)"` and then `invalidform(address){
    if(!(address.valid)){
      return true;
    }
  }` Is this correct way to implement this. This is working fine

Comment: That's good !! even if you want to implement every parameter you can do it.  To do an specific validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding a property `isValid` to `myForm.controls.addresses.controls` model then you have a property to change for every address element. Obviously you must do the validation to show or hide the validation text or error icon.

Comment: Here i do not have problem with pop up showing but when ever user try to fill a form if it is valid i have to remove error message if it is not valid i have to keep error message as it is. This must be validate all delivery addresses individually.

Comment: Ok I got it.  let me  modify my answer